# GWT: Fragments & Modules

Tags: java, gwt, module, fragment

I understand the difference between initial, exclusive and leftover fragments in GWT, but what I don't understand is their relationship to modules/entry points. Is a module simply an initial fragment? If that's the case, and my app actually has multiple modules defined for it, then I would assume that means it has multiple initial fragments as well, yes?

If I'm wrong here, then what is the difference between modules and fragments, and how do they relate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module compiles to a different script, which resides in a different output folder:

/war/module1/
/war/module2/

etc. where module1 and module2 are the names of your modules. Each module has its own fragments if you use code-splitting.